# What is ADS-B altitude decoding range if the Q-bit is 0 (i.e. multiple of 100 feet)?

Tags: dataframe

The ADS-B message altitude has the accuracy of +/- 25 ft when the Q-bit is 1, and the value can represent altitude from -1000 to +50175 ft.

What is the altitude range if the Q-bit is 0 (i.e. +/- 100 ft)?